# What causes the unexpected rotation of 3D models in between NLA tracks?

Tags: animation

I am using blender 2.82a and can't figure out why my 3D model rotates unexpectedly between NLA tracks when Blend Out is used. I've checked the rotation values in the viewport but nothing changes when the model rotates. As you can see the image, the model is in a 45 degree angle, the model should be standing straight. [image: Model rotates unexpectedly in NLA]

Comment: This is just a guess, since I'm still trying to get my head around the NLA. But it seems that the Hold, and Hold Forward features are very important when you're using multiple contributing strips, because, and I'm not entirely certain about this, but it SEEMS that the default behavior is for Blender to try and revert your rig to its default pose IF and WHEN it is at a point in the timeline for which no strips are currently influencing it. UNLESS you have the Hold options employed. Sorry if this misleads, but it's at least worth exploring. I hope to know more about how this works, eventually.